# Suggestion on injecting a React App Widget on a host website using iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, widget, aws-amplify

I'm making a chat widget, which will be embeddable to any website using an iframe. Previously I made a react app and then bundled everything to ONE bundle.js file and hosted it on S3(or any static file hosting platform) with public access and then inject that file inside the website with iframe (using the script tag). That bundle.js file has a size of nearly 1.23 MBs. I suspect that it can affect the speed of the website loading.

I have tried one more thing, I created the same react app and deployed it on AWS Amplify, and then use the link of that app in the iframe instead of hosting a static bundle.js file.
Is the latter one a good approach or the former (bundle.js) was better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out that the latter approach (Running the app in AWS Amplify) takes more time to load hence is not that useful than hosting a static file on S3. However, I found that CloudFront can improve the speed and also add cache support for it.